# What's the reason of my dependencies code?

Tags: android

Here's my Code for developing Android Application with Android Studio.
At build.gradle(Module), when I change targetSdkVersion 27 to 28, the Code does not working. The app can't not log-in server and search data in Mysql. Exactly, the server has no response. 
But, when setting targetSdkVersion with 27, it works well.
The error caused from Android 3.2.
FYI, I'm developing app with Apache, Php, Mysql.

Please, tell me the answer of my problem setting targetSdkVersion...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mjc.kjs.myregistration"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27  //?
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
          "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
        layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 
    'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your Logcat?

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to set `targetSdkVersion 28` - else you'd target the wrong API level.

...because `targetSdkVersion` also dictates which `buildToolsVersion` is used.

`the Code does not working` is not an error description; just fix the code.